# Creating empty lists with the name of the elements of another list

Tags: python, list

Say we have a list as `my_list=["a","b","c"]`. What I want to do is to create empty lists as

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
```

so that I can append some elements into them according to their names.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A list of lists will probably work well here.

Comment: You probably wan't a `dict` where keys are `a`, `b`, `c` and values are empty lists.

Comment: If you want to add elements to a list based on a name, maybe you could use a dictionary with the names as keys and lists as values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, it uses the function `exec` to execute the command as if it were typed by you but you use `i` as a dynamic variable name

```
for i in my_list:
  exec(i+'=[]')
```

Keep in mind this isn't very safe to do

Answer (score 18):

Programmatically making variables is a very bad idea. Make a dictionary instead with those names as keys:

```
my_lists = {key:[] for key in my_list}
```

Then you can append to them like this:

```
my_lists['a'].append(some_data)
```

This also gives you the advantage of easily being able to loop through them if you need to.

Comment: I already upvoted this, but thinking ahead to the future when some new Python programmer finds this post and asks "why is programmatically making variables a bad idea?" Can you expound a bit on why you said this?

Comment: It's a bad idea for many reasons. 1) if you are making variables from user input, the user could easily overwrite one of your variables or try to use a keyword 2) it effectively disables tools in IDEs that track variables, making debugging a nightmare 3) logically grouped things should stay in groups; this makes looping easier and most groups of things need a loop at some point 4) reading these variables will involve another messy `exec` call. 5) if you don't know how many variables were created you need another hacky approach to inspect the local namespace. 6) Other reasons I'm sure ...

Comment: @Novel actually you only need an `eval` call to read such variables but that's still a bad thing, so I totally agree with you

Comment: will this method preserve the ordering of lists?