# Create a list for each item in another list

Tags: python, list

How can I create an empty list for each item on another list (variable in length). where the to be created list name contains the item value.

i.e.

> ['NSW', 'ACT', 'VIC']

newly created lists

> NSW_list[]
>
> ACT_list[]
>
> VIC_list[]

Comment: Use a dict of list? `lists = {x:[] for x in ['NSW', 'ACT', 'VIC']}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating empty lists with the name of the elements of another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771692/creating-empty-lists-with-the-name-of-the-elements-of-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this course of action.

You will probably get all kind of replies telling how you *can* do this using `setattr` and friends, but in practice dynamically-created variable names are almost invariably (see what I did there?) a bad idea.

Suppose you already have a variable called `X_list` and then you process a list containing `'X'`. Your variable will have been overwritten.

Further, since you cannot know in advance what variable names will have been created, you will be forced to use dynamic techniques like `getattr` to access them. This almost guarantees your code will be obscure and difficult to read.

If you REALLY want to access them by name the easiest way to do this is to use the names as keys for a dictionary. This is about the simplest way to do that.

```
list_dict = {}
for name in ['NSW', 'ACT', 'VIC']:
    list_dict[name+'_list'] = []
```

My preference would be to drop the `'_list'` suffix and simply use the names as they appear in the list.

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
L=['NSW', 'ACT', 'VIC']

empty_list=[[]]*len(L)
```

output:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Now if you want with old lists then just zip them :

```
print(list(zip(L,empty_list)))
```

output:

```
[('NSW', []), ('ACT', []), ('VIC', [])]
```